# How to write a function wrong_prime that takes no arguement and should return the first prime p for which q = 2^p - 1 is not prime

Tags: python, primes

> 500 years ago it was believed that all numbers q of the form q = 2^p -
>   1 are prime if p is prime.
>
> Write a function wrong_prime that takes no arguments. It should return
>   the first prime p for which q = 2^p - 1 is not prime.
>
> Hint: this number should be between 10 and 15.

The code I have come up with is the following but does not work

```
def isprime(n):

  if n < 2:

    return False

  elif n == 2:

    return True

  else:

    if n % 2 == 0:

      return False

    for i in range(3,n,2):
      if n % i == 0:
        return False
    return True

def wrong_prime():

  for i in range(1,):

    q = 2**i-1
    if isprime(i) and isprime(q) == False:
        print(q)
```

When inputting wrong_function there is no output

Can anyone help produce a working function?

Comment: (All comments relating to OP not asking a question are no longer needed and should be deleted)

Comment: Also, you don't need to check all integers in the range `range(3,2,n)`, you can settle for `range(3,2,int(sqrt(n)))` (where `sqrt` is imported from `numpy` or `math`)

Comment: I don't believe that that was believed, given how small the counterexample is. I'd like to see a source for that claim...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(1,)` is `range(0, 1)`, i.e. you are only testing `0`. If you want an open-ended range, you can use e.g. a `while` loop with an extra counting variable.

```
def wrong_prime():
  i = 1
  while True:    # fix loop
    q = 2**i-1
    if isprime(i) and isprime(q) == False:
        return i # return p, not print q
    i += 1       # remember to increment manually
```

Or using `next` with `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools
def wrong_prime():
    return next(p for p in itertools.count(1) if isprime(p) and not isprime(2**p-1))
```

(Of course, given the "Hint" you can also just use a `range(10, 16)`)

Also, note that the function should `return` the value of `p`, whereas yours *prints* `q`. For testing, call as `print(wrong_prime())` to see the value.

Comment: That code seems to work and has an output of 11 however when running through another system, it gives an error message of: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/unit_tests.py", line 29, in test_wrong_prime
    assert(wrong_prime() == 11), \
AssertionError: 
        The function 'wrong_prime' has failed.
        It should return another value. I'll give you a hint, it's an ODD number! ;-)

Comment: @JordynTaylor See my update. Seems like the function is expected to `return`, not `print` the number.